# Currency code is not displaying in open JDK 11(EX :INR 1,000.00 )

Tags: java

I am trying to display the currency like below format in open JDK 11 using NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale(lan, getCountry));

I am getting below output
"₹ 1,000" as per our requirement I need to show like "INR 1,000"(instead of currency symbol need to display currency code like INR, USD, PHP ...).

please find attached the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Currency curency = getCurrency(356);
        String currencyCode = curency.getCurrencyCode();
        System.out.println("currency2--->"+currencyCode);
        Locale locale =getLocalFromISO(currencyCode);
          String getCountry =locale.getCountry();
        System.out.println("locale-getCountry--->"+getCountry);
        String lan = locale.toString();
        System.out.println("Locale-->"+lan);
        Locale usa = new Locale(lan, getCountry);
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale(lan, getCountry));
        System.out.println("Formated Amount---->" +currencyFormatter.format(Double.parseDouble("100000000")));
}
          
public static Currency getCurrency(int numericCurrencyCode) {
            Currency currencyOutput = null;
            for (Currency currency : currencySet) {
                if (currency.getNumericCode() == numericCurrencyCode) {
                    currencyOutput = currency;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return currencyOutput;
        }
public static Locale getLocalFromISO(String iso4217code){
        Locale locl = null;
        for (Locale locale : NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
            String code = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
           System.out.println(code);
            if (iso4217code.equals(code)) {
                locl = locale;
                break;
            }
        }
        return locl;
    }
```

Comment: Well, the `NumberFormat` you get would use the currency symbol and as far as I know you can't set it to use the code instead. So you'd either need to build your own `DecimalFormat` (not too hard) or just format the number and prepend the code yourself.

Comment: @Thomas including comma and decimal places based on country how I can do it fro DecimalFormat can you explain?

Comment: @user16320675 including comma and decimal places based on country how I can do it fro DecimalFormat can you explain?

Comment: You could have a look at the implementation of `getCurrencyInstance()` to see what it does. Basically it pulls the number format from resource bundles based on the locale that was passed and if possible adjusts the maximum fraction digits based on the currency by using `Currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()` and `NumberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(...)` and `NumberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(...)` (have a look at the source of `NumberFormatProviderImpl.adjustForCurrencyDefaultFractionDigits(...)`).